# Excel VBA Find Next command

Tags: vba, excel

I'm having a problem with the FindNext Command. This code, based on the value of "wash.offset(1, 0)", will try to find the nth instance of the Row of YAxis2 in sheet1. If "wash.offset(1, 0) = 1" then it will find the first instance, which works fine. However, the problem occurs when "wash.offset(1, 0) = <> 1" then I want to loop through the FindNext instance of for the value of "wash.offset(1,0)". However, I keep getting the Error *"Unable to get the FindNext property of the Range class"*

**Here is the code for this**

```
    'Find Row
    If wash.offset(1, 0) = 1 Then
        'wash.offset(1, 1).Select
        'Yaxis = ActiveCell.Value
        ' Set the variable Yaxis to the string value that is located in wash.offset(1, 1)
        MsgBox "we are in the wash.offset(1,0) = 1 part of the loop"
        Yaxis = wash.offset(1, 1)

            'Set wsThis = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
            'wsThis.Range("E13").Value = instno
            ' This line of code is definitely needed ... lots of troubleshooting discoevered this
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select

            '
            Set Yaxis2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=Yaxis)

            Yaxis2.Select
            CellRow = ActiveCell.Row
            MsgBox "CellRow = " & CellRow
        Else 'elseif  wash.offset(1, 0) <> 1 Then

        MsgBox "wash.offset(1, 0) = " & wash.offset(1, 0)

            ' Find first instance of value
            Set Yaxis2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Find(What:=Yaxis)
            cellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
            ' This loop cycle through the FindNext function the no. times that value in "wash.offset(1, 0)" is equal to
            For innerLoop = 1 To wash.offset(1, 0) - 1
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Select
                Set Yaxis2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.FindNext("cellAddress")
                cellAddress = ActiveCell.Address
            Next innerLoop

            Yaxis2.Select
            CellRow = ActiveCell.Row
            MsgBox "CellRow = " & CellRow
    End If
```

**Here is where I'm getting the error**

Set Yaxis2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.FindNext("cellAddress")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues in your code, but the error is caused by the parameter used for FindNext() - it should be a Range object, not a String

The next issue is that FindNext() will not activate the next cell so your cellAddress is always the same

A generic function to illustrate how to use FindNext:

```
Option Explicit

Sub findAllValues()

    Dim foundCell As Range, foundAdr As String

    With Worksheets(1).Range("A1:A10")

        Set foundCell = .Find("TestString", LookIn:=xlValues)

        If Not foundCell Is Nothing Then

            foundAdr = foundCell.Address

            Do

                MsgBox foundCell.Address

                Set foundCell = .FindNext(foundCell)

            Loop While Not foundCell Is Nothing And foundCell.Address <> foundAdr

        End If

    End With

End Sub
```